# SQL: I am getting only one row as output where I should be getting 4. What's wrong with my code

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This is the code that I am using

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_bonus @bonus      INT, 
                          @lastname   VARCHAR(50) out, 
                          @firstname  VARCHAR(50) out, 
                          @dateofhire DATE out, 
                          @salary     SMALLMONEY out, 
                          @bonusmoney SMALLMONEY out 
AS 
    IF @bonus = 20 
      BEGIN 
          SELECT @lastname = lastname, 
                 @firstname = firstname, 
                 @dateofhire = dateofhire, 
                 @salary = salary, 
                 @bonusmoney = ( salary * ( @bonus ) * 0.01 ) 
          FROM   salesreps 
          WHERE  dateofhire < '12/31/2000' 
      END 

    IF @bonus = 5 
      BEGIN 
          SELECT @lastname = lastname, 
                 @firstname = firstname, 
                 @dateofhire = dateofhire, 
                 @salary = salary, 
                 @bonusmoney = ( salary * ( @bonus ) * 0.01 ) 
          FROM   salesreps 
          WHERE  dateofhire >= '12/31/2000' 
      END 

    DECLARE @lastname   VARCHAR(50), 
            @firstname  VARCHAR(50), 
            @dateofhire DATE, 
            @salary     SMALLMONEY, 
            @bonusmoney SMALLMONEY 

    EXEC Sp_bonus 
      @bonus=20, 
      @lastname=@lastname out, 
      @firstname=@firstname out, 
      @dateofhire=@dateofhire out, 
      @salary=@salary out, 
      @bonusmoney=@bonusmoney out 

    SELECT lastname=@lastname, 
           firstname=@firstname, 
           dateofhire=@dateofhire, 
           salary=@salary, 
           bonus=@bonusmoney
```

The result of this is

```
 Lastname   Firstname  Dateofhire   Salary      Bonus
 Bernstein  Michael    1991-05-25   98000.00    19600.00
```

While there are 3 more records which should be here. I don't understand what I am doing wrong in the code that it is only giving me one output line. I checked the logic for where, which is correct, and also the calculation for bonus is coming out as correct.

The only problem is that it shows me only one line of output, whether I use bonus=20 or bonus=5

Any suggestions.

Comment: The first issue I see is that you could really use some formatting of your code. The second issue which is a huge problem is that you are executing your procedure inside of itself. You are using culture specific date formats instead of ISO yyyy-mm-dd format. Last but not least you are using the sp_ prefix. This is reserved by MS for system procedures and should be avoided. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: I try format your code with http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm but I think you miss one `END`  there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your return values are scalars not vectors.

If you want return a table and a scalar value.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name 
                 @param int out
AS
BEGIN
    SET @param = value

    SELECT ... FROM [Table] WHERE Condition
END
GO
```

Comment: Took me sometime to understand what you were saying but understood eventually. Thanks